# How can I do a screen recording on the S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I need to record my screen as I'm using a specific app to show the issues showing up that a developer is  unable to replicate.  How can I achieve this? Is screen recording even possible on Android?

OS: 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Most screen recording applications require rooting your phone, unfortunately.

You can try [EASY screen recorder NO ROOT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.org.invisibility.recordablefree&hl=en) ([paid version here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.org.invisibility.recordable)): it is the most well-rated screen recording application that does not need root I am aware of.

A few other [applications](http://recordable.mobi/compare):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, download and install Android Studio with ADB (or ADB standalone). Open command line application in your system, and enter:

```
adb devices
```

If it shows your device connected to computer, then you are good to go. If not, turn on Developer options in your Android device and allow Debugging over USB. Reconnect device. If it's shown with previous command then type:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/movie.mp4
```

where `/sdcard/` is the place where the movie will be saved in your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a screen recording in a phone, only in a computer. But if your unit is already rooted, you can try to download "SCR Screen Recorder" from the Appstore. It will work on rooted devices only.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not rooted.

Comment: I just searched for another one(and hope this would help), 
try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bugunsoft.displayrecorder
, I guess it's a paid App, I can't find the free version. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [site](http://gs3.wonderhowto.com/how-to/capture-high-quality-video-recording-your-samsung-galaxy-s3s-screen-0146549/), you can capture your phone's screen at high frame rates into a high-quality MPEG4 video. The application is not free unfortunately, but there is a [demo version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencastfree) for free that I reccomend you to try.

Hope this helps.